# Extracting a part of simple string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Let's say I have these strings (each new line being a separate string):

```
EducationLink
BioLink
InterestsLink
```

And I wanted to extract the part that's not "Link" using Javascript. How would I do this? The expected results are

```
Education
Bio
Interests
```

I tried a Regex, but I'm not very experienced with them, and it failed:

```
/^ (^Link) $/
```

Using string functions such as slice() and substr(), I only got the values to the **right of** the selected text, not to the left as desired.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.replace()`

```
'EducationLink'.replace('Link', ''); //returns Education
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

The thing is you CAN use regex to do this replace, but being such a simple scenario (unless there is more to it) why would you overcomplicate things?

Comment: Because if there's more than one line to work on. Because there might be `Link` in the middle of the string somewhere. Because there's just so much that could go wrong with plain string substitution. Apart from that, no reason.

Comment: Neither of these scenarios are true, so this seems like the best answer.

Comment: @Kolink no need to get your knickers in a twist. The asker plainly states he has *several strings* and goes on to list them.

Answer (score 2):

```
text = input.replace(/Link(\n|$)/g,"\n");
```

Comment: If you assume that each line is an individual string, then it should go like this instead: `text = input.replace(/Link$/, '');`. I'm not sure which the OP meant, though.

Comment: Each line is a separate string, sorry about that.

Comment: The updated regex will still work, but you can simplify it to `/Link$/g` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to put the `Link` into the end of your RegEx, such as:

```
^([A-Z]+)Link$
```

This matches:

- One or more characters between A and Z
- Then the word `Link`
- Then the end of the string

The part in parentheses will be returned as a group.

Furthermore, if all you need to do is *remove* the suffix `Link`, you can use the `replace()` method in Javascript:

```
var x = myStr.replace('Link', '');
```

Comment: Oh, that was rather obvious. However, why did my RegEx not work?

Comment: Your RegEx doesn't make much sense.  The `^` character is used to match the beginning of the string, or to negate characters in a bracket group.  Such as `[^Link]` would mean any character that is neither `L`, nor `i` nor `n` nor `k`.

Comment: Ok, but I used normal parentheses (), not square brackets [].

Comment: I can't think of anything that would match your expression.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [String.split()<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var txt = 'EducationLink'.split('Link')[0]; // txt == 'Education'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<script>

var str = "EducationLink";
index = str.search(/link/i);
str = str.substr(0,index);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, if all the strings end in 'Link', just use a replace. Otherwise, any of these methods will work fine:

```
var i = 0;
var strings = [
    'EducationLink',
    'BioLink',
    'InterestsLink'
];
var s = '';
var r = /^(.+)Link$/
for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i += 1) {
    s = strings[i];
    //s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('Link')); //Uncomment for substring
    //s = s.match(r)[1]; //Uncomment for regex
    s = s.replace('Link', '');
    strings[i] = s;
}
console.log(strings);
```

Copy and paste into a browser console window to run.

To answer your question ("However, why did my RegEx not work?") in a comment on another answer, your RegEx does the following:

```
/^ (^Link) $/
//Each regex term on own line, commented below
^   //start of string
    //Literal space
(^Link) //Capturing group, string starting with 'Link'.
    //Literal space
$   //end of string
```

While you can have two "start of string" identifiers in a Regex, there will only ever be one "start of string". The `^` character is only a negation in a character class which is enclosed in square brackets, not curved. If you want to capture a literal caret (`^`), put a backslash in front of it (`\^`).